# Python – break up a bs4.element.NavigableString (xml parsed with BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

Ï have a semi-parsed xml result. I call it semi because it kind of works, and kind of don’t. This is due to the original file being a ‘semi format’.

I have tried parsing with element tree but that worked even less, so returned to parsing with BeautifulSoup.

I need help getting the name of the children, below would be ‘Line’.

I have many children, the most advanced is as follows:

```
<Line> 
<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>
<Type ref="cc-63-5c-bf-01"/>
<Base ref="8c-20-59-b7-eb"/>
<length multiplier="none" unit="m">28.536756216711005</length>
<b0ch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>
<bch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>
<r multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.03361629882328556</r>
<r0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.033624859850150575</r0>
<x multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.008802762240586673</x>
<x0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">1.1414702486684403E-05</x0>
</Line>
```

When I make a list of the information below 'Line', I get:

```
[<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>, <Type ref="cc-63-5c-bf-01"/>, <Base ref="8c-20-59-b7-eb"/>, <length multiplier="none" unit="m">28.536756216711005</length>, <b0ch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>, <bch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>, <r multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.03361629882328556</r>, <r0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.033624859850150575</r0>, <x multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.008802762240586673</x>, <x0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">1.1414702486684403E-05</x0>]
```

The elements in the list, I am able to convert from bs4.element.NavigableString to string, and then sort them as I want.

But when I try to get the 'parent' of the information, it returns the whole first instant of 'children', same code as above, starting and stopping with  , .

I am not able to handle this bulk of information as a total. It can't be converted to a string as a whole.

When looping through all children, I don’t know that the first child is named , and I don’t know the next children names.

How to pick out this information without knowing the name or the length of the name?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: It looks like you're trying to parse XML. Maybe you should take a look at this simpler method, instead of using BeautifulSoup: https://www.edureka.co/blog/python-xml-parser-tutorial/

Using that method, you could just do

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
data='''
<Line> 
<ID>0b10-bd-59-ac-bac</ID>
<Type ref="cc-63-5c-bf-01"/>
<Base ref="8c-20-59-b7-eb"/>
<length multiplier="none" unit="m">28.536756216711005</length>
<b0ch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>
<bch multiplier="none" unit="S"/>
<r multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.03361629882328556</r>
<r0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.033624859850150575</r0>
<x multiplier="none" unit="ohm">0.008802762240586673</x>
<x0 multiplier="none" unit="ohm">1.1414702486684403E-05</x0>
</Line>
'''
myroot = ET.fromstring(data)
print(myroot.tag)
```

```
> Line
```

and

```
print(myroot[0].tag)
```

```
> ID
```

and

```
for x in myroot:
     print(x.tag, x.attrib, x.text)
```

```
> ID {} 0b10-bd-59-ac-bac
> Type {'ref': 'cc-63-5c-bf-01'} None
> Base {'ref': '8c-20-59-b7-eb'} None
> length {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'm'} 28.536756216711005
> b0ch {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'S'} None
> bch {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'S'} None
> r {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'ohm'} 0.03361629882328556
> r0 {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'ohm'} 0.033624859850150575
> x {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'ohm'} 0.008802762240586673
> x0 {'multiplier': 'none', 'unit': 'ohm'} 1.1414702486684403E-05
```

and for example:

```
myroot[3].tag, myroot[3].attrib['unit'], myroot[3].text
```

```
> ('length', 'm', '28.536756216711005')
```

Comment: The problem is getting the text/name 'Line' , I can use the elements in the list, but the list only contains information in the level below 'Line'.

Comment: Could you post the code? I still think the solution is just not using the names, or making a list of names first.

Comment: I fixed the question to make it about actually parsing it in a much easier way. BeautifulSoup is pretty complicated if you ask me. Please accept the answer if you like it, I'm new here and trying to farm some reputation :)

Comment: Thanks, but as mentioned in the intro, I have tried parsing with element tree, it dosen't work. I am not sure why (file setup I guess). BeautifulSoup works partly, I get some functions to work after parsing, and some don't. My problem now is that I can read all the lines, but not the first and last ('Line'). When I try to ask for 'parent' of one strings, I get the whole combined thing. I am not able to separate out the 'Line' info'. The whole combined thing is a bs4.element.NavigableString, which again means converting to string isn't possible (or I haven't found a way. yet).

Comment: The code in the question is what it looks like after parsing. 'Line' is one of the top-level 'children' from the xml file.

Comment: The code I posted works fine in python 3.9 as I demonstrated. What do you mean with file setup? What version are you on? Post the entire code and a file if you want help